# How to handle multiple parameters in @SQLDelete?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-annotations

I have a @SQLDelete annotation defined as -

```
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE item SET deleted = 1  WHERE id = ? and version=? ")
```

when I am calling delete on `item` I am not able to pass `version` and I am getting the following exception -

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not delete:
com.hk.domain.order.Item#30000004]; SQL [UPDATE item SET deleted = 1  WHERE id = ? and
version=? ]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not
delete: [com.hk.domain.order.Item#30000004]
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:629)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateAccessor.java:412)
.
.
.
.
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 2
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1055)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:926)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.checkAllParametersSet(PreparedStatement.java:2513)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.addBatch(PreparedStatement.java:1007)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.addBatch(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:175)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.addBatch(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:175)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.addToBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:53)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2548)
... 93 more
```

I assumed the version should be picked up from `item` object itself, but that's not happening.

Is there anyway to pass the version? How to go about with this annotation when there are more than 1 parameter? I looked everywhere but could not get any solution for the cases where there are 2 parameters.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can u use a object param list? for more then one argument. Another possible solution is that you have a base class where version is included??

Comment: Can please you add your full `Item` class to the question?

Comment: Annotate version field with @Version